# Terraform not found by a jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, containers, terraform

So I'm running jenkins inside a docker container with terraform installed on it.
I have a pipeline which automate the `"Terraform init, plan,..."` procedure. However, every time I launch a build, I get this error

> "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Terra_pipeline_main@tmp/durable-1fd048ee/script.sh:
> 1:
> /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Terra_pipeline_main@tmp/durable-1fd048ee/script.sh:
> Terraform: not found".

It seems that Terraform isn't found even though it's installed (I checked on docker container CLI if terraform is really installed with a `"terraform --help"` and it worked).

I can't figure out what's the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugMPk.png)

Comment: At a minimum, we would need to see the JP code to assist with this question. If the image is not publicly available in the Docker registry, then we would also need to see the Dockerfile for it. If I had to guess, it sounds like you have a typo in the code where you are executing `Terraform` instead of `terraform`.

Comment: Hello Matt !
Thank you for your help. Indeed I was getting that error due toa typo in my code.
I apologize for not adding any images. (It's my first on Stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. Indeed I was getting that error due to a typo in my code. I apologize for not adding any images. (It's my first on Stack)
To solve this problem, just write "terraform" instead of "Terraform" with no capital letters. @Matt schuchard